# 1 file can't have https

Tags: wordpress, http, https, vimeo

Vimeo continues to be an https problem. I have a WordPress multisite on an https server. On most of the files, it doesn't matter whether the address is http or https. But, there is one page with Vimeo. I need to be sure that particular page is only accessed with http so the video works. The cause of the problem is that links coming off the https pages pick up https automatically. The following doesn't break the page, but keeps the https.

```
# 9/23/13 Vimeo address should not be reached through https
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /wordpress-page-with-vimeo
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://wordpress-site.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I assume your question is, how to solve your re-write since its not working. Wouldn't it be like this?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^/wordpress-page-with-vimeo(.*) http://wordpress-site.com/wordpress-page-with-vimeo$1 [L,R=301]
```

Note: This hasn't been tested since I don't have access to my local web server right now.